# QuickChecking functor law for Wrap typeclass

Tags: haskell, functor

I wrote a code for testing Functor laws of two datatypes, "Constant" and "Wrap". I completed code for quickchecking Constant datatype, but I got stuck in Wrap datatype. ("wrapGen" function) I tried but I can't implement the "wrapGen" function. Can I get some hint?

Many Thanks.

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Function  -- for Fun
 
-- Functor laws
functorIdentity :: (Functor f, Eq (f a)) => f a -> Bool
functorIdentity f = fmap id f == f

functorCompose :: (Eq (f c), Functor f) => f a -> Fun a b -> Fun b c -> Bool 
functorCompose x (Fun _ f) (Fun _ g) = (fmap (g . f) x) == (fmap g . fmap f $ x)

-- ┌--------------------------------------------┐
-- | Constant datatype (Example)                |
-- └--------------------------------------------┘

newtype Constant a b = Constant { getConstant :: a } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor (Constant m) where
  fmap _ (Constant v) = Constant v

instance (Arbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary (Constant a b) where
  arbitrary = constGen

constGen :: (Arbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Gen (Constant a b)
constGen = do
  a <- arbitrary
  return (Constant a)  

type IntToInt = Fun Int Int
type ConstFC = (Constant Int Int) -> IntToInt -> IntToInt -> Bool

test_Const :: IO ()
test_Const = do
  quickCheck $ \x -> functorIdentity(x :: Constant Int Int)
  quickCheck (functorCompose' :: ConstFC)

-- ┌--------------------------------------------┐
-- | Wrap datatype (Question)                   |
-- └--------------------------------------------┘

data Wrap f a = Wrap (f a) deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor f => Functor (Wrap f) where
  fmap f (Wrap fa) = Wrap (fmap f fa)

instance (Functor f, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Wrap f a) where
  arbitrary = wrapGen

wrapGen :: (Functor f, Arbitrary a) => Gen (Wrap f a)
wrapGen = undefined  -- TODO: How can I implement this? 

type WrapFC = (Constant Int Int) -> IntToInt -> IntToInt -> Bool

qcWrap :: IO ()
qcWrap = do 
  quickCheck $ \x -> functorIdentity (x :: Wrap Maybe Int)
  quickCheck (functorCompose :: WrapFC)
```

Comment: What have you tried, how did it fail?

Comment: I couldn't implement `wrapGen` function for QuickCheck test. (I marked "TODO" at the line.)

Comment: Well, it's not possible in general – consider `Wrap (Const Void) Int`, which does not contain any values at all. You'll need to restrict what functors are allowed, or even define separate instances for individual functors.

Comment: You can either use the `Arbitrary1` class or just use `FlexibleContexts` with `instance Arbitrary (f a) => Arbitrary (Wrap f a) where ...`